# Mysterious annotations showing up on decompiled code after using Proguard

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I just tested out proguard to obfuscate my android app.

But decompiling the apk shows that obfuscated functions have a weird annotation on top of them that displays the real function name, the real class name AND the real file name. How is that possible? Why is this happening?

The decompiled code looks like this,

```
   @f(c = "com.my.app.package.Classname", f = "Classname.kt", l = {49, 51}, m = "RealFunctionName")
public static final class b extends i.b0.j.a.d {
    public /* synthetic */ Object s;
    public int t;
    public final /* synthetic */ Classname u;
    public Object v;
    public Object w;
    public Object x;

    /* JADX INFO: super call moved to the top of the method (can break code semantics) */
    public b(Classname classname, i.b0.d dVar) {
        super(dVar);
        this.u = classname;
    }

    @Override // i.b0.j.a.a
    public final Object l(Object obj) {
        this.s = obj;
        this.t |= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        return this.u.c(this);
    }
}
```

This happens even if I remove ALL proguard rules to make it obfuscate everything without any exceptions. So where does this annotation come from? And why does it happen? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/languages/kotlin

Comment: That doesn't really help since those rules are for things I want to avoid obfuscating. Which isn't what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I was just linking the documentation that explains the situations in which it does or does not strip away the names in the meta data. I'm not personally knowledgeable but I would check your configuration closely.

Comment: Have you checked in the mapping file what the original annotation was? (`-printmapping mapping.txt`)

Comment: Okay, that just made me realize something useful. These mysterious annotations only occur on top of suspend functions. Regular functions do not have this annotation on top of them. Still don't know how I can get rid of them, but I'm one step closer now. Thanks!

Comment: That's probably the `kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.DebugMetadata` annotation? ProGuard should remove it be default, unless there is a keep rule for it (https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard/blob/master/base/src/main/java/proguard/shrink/AnnotationUsageMarker.java#L276).